# spring-boot application.properties are not overwriten

Tags: spring-boot

I have one class:

```
package com.example.propertyorder;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value="file:C:\\TEMP\\property-order.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)

public class PropertyOrderApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext run = SpringApplication.run(PropertyOrderApplication.class, args);
        Environment env = (Environment) run.getBean("environment");
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("my.value"));
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("my.value2"));
    }
}
```

and I have one `application.properties` file:

```
my.value=application.properties
```

and I have my external properties file `C:\\TEMP\\property-order.properties`:

```
my.value=property-order.properties
my.value2=gotcha
```

but the result is always:

```
application.properties
gotcha
```

instead of:

```
property-order.properties
gotcha
```

So it looks like, that spring-boot's application.properties overrules all.
Is there a way to fix it.
The only solution that i found is to not use the `application.properties`, but a `my-app.properties` instead and place that one before my external file in the ProperySource-tree:

```
@PropertySource(value="classpath:my-app.properties")
@PropertySource(value="file:C:\\TEMP\\property-order.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

Is there a better way, so that I can stay with the `application.properties` ?

***edit:***

*added missing value2 to the property file*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual behavior is conform to the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) :

> Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is
>   designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Properties are
>   considered in the following order:
>
> ....
>
> 14.Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
>
> 15.Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
>
> 16.@PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes.

The `application.properties` (inside or outside the jar) have a higher priority (14 and 15 respectively) than any `@PropertySource` annotations added in `@Configuration` class (16).

> *Is there a better way, so that I can stay with the
>   application.properties ?*

Of course you can use any of the 13 higher priority ways :

> 1.Devtools global settings properties on your home directory
>   (~/.spring-boot-devtools.properties when devtools is active).
>
> 2.@TestPropertySource annotations on your tests.
>
> 3.@SpringBootTest#properties annotation attribute on your tests. Command
>   line arguments.
>
> 4.Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an
>   environment variable or system property).
>
> 5.ServletConfig init parameters.
>
> 6.ServletContext init parameters.
>
> 7.JNDI attributes from java:comp/env.
>
> 8.Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
>
> 9.OS environment variables.
>
> 10.A RandomValuePropertySource that has properties only in random.*.
>
> 11.Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar
>   (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
>
> 12.Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar
>   (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
>
> 13.Application properties outside of your packaged jar
>   (application.properties and YAML variants).

For example renaming `property-order.properties` to `application-order.properties` to make it a Spring Boot profile properties and run your application with `order` as active profile would give it a higher priority and so it should be enough :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PropertyOrderApplication {...}
```

Comment: well, I thought the list from the docu is from top to bottom, means that all the later overwrites the earlier!? But it seems, that they are not. Anyway the goal is, that I have a `war` which is deployed in a wildfly, and so I cannot put any commandline arguments or environments to that `war` for telling spring where the external application-PROFILE.properties is located.

Comment: Indeed it is the other way ! Whatever the server and the way which the spring boot app is deployed you can specify the profile. For example if you use a `web.xml` you can specify `spring.profiles.active` with the wished profile. You may also modify the .bat/.sh to run the JVM for Wildfly to add a java option that sets the profile such as `java ... -Dspring.profiles.active=xxxprofile`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the property defined int the application.properties, you can use the below approach.

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "file:/user/home/external.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }


}
```

Comment: sorry that doesn't work, the result is the again `application.properties`